# Using wkWebView to open URL and deeplink but not via safari

Tags: safari, swift4, wkwebview, xcode10

This is regarding wkWebview. I want to use wkWebView for my app for the whole operation of browsing internet and when it comes to deep link, I want it to check the apps in phone and open it (if it is available). I know we can use UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL and open method but I think if I use these methods, it will open the safari first and then let the safari do the job for the deep link. I dont want to involve safari at all in this case. So folks, can you please help me? Is there any way that I can exclude safari when I use canOpenURL and Open method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set ***WkWebView*** Delegate :

```
 webView.uiDelegate = self
 webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Then implement the following method.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
                let host = url.host, !host.hasPrefix("something whatever you want to handle deeplink"),
                UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                print(url)
                print("No need to open it locally")
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            } else {
                print("Open it locally")
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        } else {
            print("not a user click")
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
```

Do let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me to come out with my own answer. I'll accept this as accepted answer anyway.

Comment: @Ketan, In case "print("No need to open it locally")" if code come to this way, then it will call some methods in app delegate or sceneDelegate to open deeplinks? Wright?

Comment: @DmitriyGrehsure I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I managed to achieve this by checking the scheme. I realized that when the url starts with "https/http", it will try to open safari if only the app is not available in our phone. This is what I want to prevent from which is why I check the scheme first. With this, when url contains http/https, it will stays on the wkwebview. I managed to achieve my aim with this method, but I always open to any suggestions or improvements.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        if let url = navigationAction.request.url, let scheme = url.scheme?.lowercased() {
            //check the url scheme to bring user to specific apps other than safari

            if scheme != "https" && scheme != "http" {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
                    // use the available apps in user's phone
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                } 
            }
        }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```